# Symfony : problems when fetching data from DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm a beginner in Symfony and I have to develop a web site with it so I created all the functionalities but I'm blocked in the search functionality I have to get data from my DB based on a keyword typed on a text field. I created all the code displayed below this paragraph, but when I try to search for something I get this  error :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 14 near
>   'Tunipharma\PharmacieBundle\Pharmacie': Error: Class
>   'Tunipharma\PharmacieBundle\Pharmacie' is not defined.

this is the function in the controller:

```
public function searchAction() {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -- Recherche Pharmacie :
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
$sform = $this->createForm(new SearchPharmacieFormType());

$request = $this->get('request');
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
$sform->bind($request);

    if ($sform->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->request->get('SearchPharmacieFormType');

        $pharmacie = $em->getRepository("PharmacieBundle:Pharmacie")-  
        >findPharmacieByParametres($data);

        return $this->render('Tunipharma:PharmacieBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig',    
        array('Pharmacies' => $pharmacie));
       }
       }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

return $this->render('PharmacieBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig', array(
            'formSearchPharmacie' => $sform->createView(),
));
}
```

This is the repository class:

```
  namespace Tunipharma\PharmacieBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
   use Tunipharma\PharmacieBundle\Entity\Pharmacie;
  /**
 * PharmacieRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
  class PharmacieRepository extends EntityRepository
   {

    public function findPharmacieByParametres($search)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->add('select','p')
                    ->add('from','Pharmacie p')
                    ->add('where','p.nom = :name')
                    ->setParameter('name',$search)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
    }
```

The form:

```
namespace Tunipharma\PharmacieBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SearchPharmacieFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('Pharmacie', 'search', array('required' => true))
        ;
    }

    public function getName() {

    }

   }
```

The block that will display the form and the result of the query:

```
      <div class="body3">
       <div class="main zerogrid">


        <form action="{{ path('search_page') }}" method="POST">

                       {{ form_widget(formSearchPharmacie) }}
            <input type="submit"/>

          </form>



        <div id="googleMap"></div>


        <div class="pharmalist"></div> 



      </div>
    </div>
```

and thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your repository like this :

```
public function findPharmacieByParametres($search)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

    return $qb
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('p.nom', ':name'))
        ->setParameter('name', $search)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

And your form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('search', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
        ));
}
```

And your controller :

```
public function searchAction()
{
    $sform = $this->createForm(new SearchPharmacieFormType());
    if ($sform->handleRequest($this->get('request'))->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $search = $sform->get('search')->getData();
        $pharmacies = $em->getRepository('TunipharmaPharmacieBundle:Pharmacie')->findPharmacieByParametres($search);

        return $this->render('TunipharmaPharmacieBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig',
            array('Pharmacies' => $pharmacies)
        );
    }

    return $this->render('TunipharmaPharmacieBundle:Default:recherche.html.twig', array(
        'formSearchPharmacie' => $sform->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanx i tried your code but in the //repository  that you wrote  in the line "->getResult" a error hint is shown and it tells me to "Remove empty statement" !!

Comment: Sorry, forgot a parenthesis.

Comment: Do you know your Symfony version ?

Comment: it is the version 2.4.3